# Empty result set if left joined table not empty otherwise null

Tags: mysql, null, left-join

Im getting some unexpected results in my sql query.
If the table I join on has records I get an empty result set back when I should get a set with null on each row and I have no idea why that is?

When yesterdays data is still in the table I get an `empty result set`. If I empty the table and run same query I get the expected result set:

```
cnt | partner | today
0   | 3000    | NULL
0   | 3001    | NULL
0   | 3002    | NULL
0   | 3003    | NULL
0   | 3004    | NULL
0   | 3005    | NULL
0   | 3006    | NULL
0   | 3007    | NULL
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE `partner` (
    `id`          INT          UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'unik räknare' ,
    `url`         TEXT                  NOT NULL                COMMENT 'webadress' ,
    `imgurl`      TEXT                  NOT NULL                COMMENT 'bildurl' ,
    `displayname` VARCHAR(256)          NOT NULL                COMMENT 'firmanamn' ,
    `annons`      TEXT                  NULL                    COMMENT 'annons ord' ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3000 COMMENT = 'Tabell innehållande samarbetspartners (saps)';

CREATE TABLE `sap_daily_stats` (
    `id`          INT          UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'unik räknare' ,
    `partner`     INT          UNSIGNED NOT NULL                COMMENT 'partner.id' ,
    `servertime`  INT          UNSIGNED NOT NULL                COMMENT 'datum' ,
    `browser`     VARCHAR(256)          NOT NULL                COMMENT 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' ,
    `remoteaddr`  VARCHAR(40)           NOT NULL                COMMENT 'REMOTE_ADDR' ,
    `httpacclang` VARCHAR(72)           NULL                    COMMENT 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10000 COMMENT = 'Tabell innehållande dagens annonsstatistik';


SELECT
    COUNT(`q`.`partner`) - (
        CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`d`.`servertime`),'%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) AS `cnt`,
    `q`.`partner`,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`d`.`servertime`),'%Y-%m-%d') AS `today`
FROM `sap_quotas` `q`
LEFT JOIN `sap_daily_stats` `d`
       ON `q`.`partner` = `d`.`partner`
GROUP BY `q`.`partner`,`today`
HAVING `today` = CURDATE() OR `today` IS NULL
ORDER BY `today` IS NULL DESC,
         `cnt` ASC,
         `q`.`partner` ASC
```

Don't know if it's related to versions but this is my current setup:

Database server

```
Server: MySQL (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.21 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Web server

```
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) PHP/7.2.4
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.2.4
```

Comment: You are filtering by  `HAVING `today` = CURDATE() OR `today` IS NULL'  so you obtain only null  (today) rows ..  check if you have really some today = curdate() .. or tray remove the having clause and che the result

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? I've shown the expected resultset.

It's when the rows in the table is from not today I get an empty result set when I should get a result set with 8 rows all having null on today.

Comment: Anyway. If I remove `HAVING today = CURDATE() OR today IS NULL` rows from yesterday show up and thats not the intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data for yesterday (as per OP) - then the LEFT JOIN will not create rows where the `today` column is null. 
One way of getting the null is to have filter in the JOIN conditions (as shown below) rather than in the HAVING conditions.

```
LEFT JOIN `sap_daily_stats` `d`
       ON `q`.`partner` = `d`.`partner` 
          and DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`d`.`servertime`),'%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```